# Load csv file from another directory in Matlab

Tags: matlab, path, filepath

I have a bunch of files that I want to import. I have classified them into different directories. Here is what I want to do:

```
file1 = '/directory1/directory2/myfile.csv';
M     = csvread(file1,1,0);
```

but this does not work. The output on the command window is:

```
Error using csvread
File not found.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a big difference between

```
file1 = '/directory1/directory2/myfile.csv';
```

and

```
file1 = 'directory1/directory2/myfile.csv';
```

The first is an absolute path that begins at the root of your file system. The second is a relative path – relative to your present working directory (where you navigated to in the command window or the location of your M-file, see [`pwd`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pwd.html)). You can use either form, but whichever you use needs to exist. If your CSV data reside in a particular folder relative to your script or M-file it's easy to use relative paths. Otherwise if you run different scripts that are located in different places on this data you'll want to specify the absolute path.

To obtain the absolute path of a file given it's relative path (or just its name if you're in the same directory) you can use the [`fileattrib`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileattrib.html) function:

```
s = fileattrib(file_relpath);
file_abspath = s.Name;
```

Comment: Perfect, that did the trick! I first used './directory1/file1' and did not work.

Comment: @SolalAmouyal: Great. I just added a bit about finding the absolute path via `fileattrib` that might be helpful.